# Can I check the archive's code in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I want to know if I can check the code of an archive generated with Xcode for an IOS app.

EDIT:

I ask this because I need to verify a generated version of my project which was uploaded before to AppStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Since when you archive an app, you get an .ipa file, or a XCArchive.

.ipa files are already compiled, and XCArchives have your compiled app in it, so you can't easily get the code from it.

But what I've tried to do with my own application is use Hopper Dissambler: http://www.hopperapp.com. It attempts to create "pseudocode" (from the executable) so you can kinda read it easier.